# Replacing Commas with <br /> and render correctly in sent emails

Tags: php, email

I have an array that might contain one or multiple items and I want to be able to email it on form submit but have it display each item on a new line, the items are separated by commas.

i.e. the array looks like this 6-7,4-7,2-5,

I have this so far:

```
$in = $register_order['product_id_array'];
$out = str_replace(',', '<br />', $in);
```

but the email renders out like:

```
6-7<br />4-7<br />2-5<br />
```

and I'd like it to render like:

6-7
4-7
2-5

Thank you!

Comment: try using a linefeed character ( `PHP_EOL` ) rather than the break tag

Comment: Add file header content type. $headers = "Content-Type: text/html;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to send HTML emails with PHP do the following :

```
$to = 'email@example.com';

$subject = 'Hello there this is my email';

$header = "From: " . $name . "\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
$header .= "CC: email@example.com\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

$content = '<html><body>';
$content .= 'hello' . '<br />' . 'hello';
$content .= '</body></html>';

mail($to, $subject, $content, $header);
```

The all important part lies in the header section of the mail. The content type informs that it has to be read as HTML content.

Comment: >2016 >using ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

If it is actually printing out the tag `<br />`, then you need to set the `content-type` header to `text/html`. Or, if the `<br />` tag is the only HTML in the email, simply replace it with `\r\n` - make sure `\r\n` is in double quotes instead of single.

Answer (score -1):

```
$in = $register_order['product_id_array'];
$out = str_replace(',', '!n', $in);
```

or

```
$in = $register_order['product_id_array'];
$out = str_replace(',', '/r/n', $in);
```

try this code

Comment: I think that perhaps ought to be `$out = str_replace(',', "\r\n", $in);`?